# ActionBar not displaying for each activity (Only Displaying for one activity)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I tried setting my action bar for each activity (in the .java file) and it won't load for each activity except for only one (FunnyActivity.java) can anyone help?

FunnyActivity.java onCreateOptionsMenu

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu items for use in the action bar
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.funny_menu, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

GunsActivity.java onCreateOptionsMenu

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu items for use in the action bar
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.guns_menu, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Thanks for any responses.

```
<activity
        android:name="com.tropicalstudios.soundboard.FunnyActivity"
        android:label="Funny Sounds"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        android:launchMode="singleTask" >
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.tropicalstudios.soundboard.GunsActivity"
        android:label="Gun Sounds"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"
        android:launchMode="singleTask" >
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.tropicalstudios.soundboard.Miscellaneous"
        android:label="Miscellaneous Sounds"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"
        android:launchMode="singleTask" >
    </activity>
```

Comment: where is your activity  code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can hide/show the `ActionBar` by calling `show();` to show, and `hide();` to hide it. If you are using API level 7, 8, or 10, use `getSupportActionBar()`, and don't forget to import appcompat-v7 library. Then, extends your class with `ActionBarActivity` instead of `Activity`. For API level 11 and higher, just call `getActionBar()`. Here's an example for you:

```
// extend this class with "Activity" for API 11+
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // For API 10 and lower only
    getSupportActionBar().show(); // call hide() if you want to hide it.

    // For API 11 and higher only
    getActionBar().show(); // call hide() if you want to hide it.
```

Please learn more about [**ActionBar**](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html).

Answer (score 1):

If you need hide actionBar in some activity try can call `getActionBar().hide()` or `getSupportActionBar().hide()` if you use support library

Answer (score 0):

The AndroidManifest file can define what style you have setup for a given Activity. If you have modified this, or only have a theme setup for one activity, then it won't affect the other activities.  For instance, if you have an Activity setup like this in the manifest XML file:

```
<activity android:name=".AlertFailedCommunications"
          android:label="@string/alert_account_label"
          android:screenOrientation="portrait"
          android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"/>
```

then it expects a dialog style screen and no action bar will be available within that screen (not the best example theme, but you get the idea).  Whereas, a theme such as this:

```
<activity android:name="MainActivity"
          android:label="@string/app_name"
          android:screenOrientation="portrait"
          android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.Light.DarkActionBar"/>
```

would provide for a dark styled action bar.  If you don't provide a theme that supports one, then you won't see one.  This could be the issue that you are having.

Comment: i've added my declaration of my activities... take a look :) Thanks for helping out, as you see I've already added the themes, it just seems like its not loading properly.